# Adding multi-line javascript to a page via DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm tinkering with some things, more just experimenting and learning how DOM manipulation works.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function()
{
        var config = {
        };
        var get = CKFinder.tools.getUrlParam;
        var getBool = function( v )
        {
            var t = get( v );

            if ( t === null )
                return null;

            return t == '0' ? false : true;
        };

        var tmp;
        if ( tmp = get( 'basePath' ) )
            CKFINDER.basePath = tmp;

        if ( tmp = get( 'startupPath' ) )
            config.startupPath = decodeURIComponent( tmp );

        config.id = get( 'id' ) || '';

        if ( ( tmp = getBool( 'rlf' ) ) !== null )
            config.rememberLastFolder = tmp;

        if ( ( tmp = getBool( 'dts' ) ) !== null )
            config.disableThumbnailSelection = tmp;

        if ( tmp = get( 'data' ) )
            config.selectActionData = tmp;

        if ( tmp = get( 'tdata' ) )
            config.selectThumbnailActionData = tmp;

        if ( tmp = get( 'type' ) )
            config.resourceType = tmp;

        if ( tmp = get( 'skin' ) )
            config.skin = tmp;

        if ( tmp = get( 'langCode' ) )
            config.language = tmp;

        // Try to get desired "File Select" action from the URL.
        var action;
        if ( tmp = get( 'CKEditor' ) )
        {
            if ( tmp.length )
                action = 'ckeditor';
        }
        if ( !action )
            action = get( 'action' );

        var parentWindow = ( window.parent == window )
            ? window.opener : window.parent;

        switch ( action )
        {
            case 'js':
                var actionFunction = get( 'func' );
                if ( actionFunction && actionFunction.length > 0 )
                    config.selectActionFunction = parentWindow[ actionFunction ];

                actionFunction = get( 'thumbFunc' );
                if ( actionFunction && actionFunction.length > 0 )
                    config.selectThumbnailActionFunction = parentWindow[ actionFunction ];
                break ;

            case 'ckeditor':
                var funcNum = get( 'CKEditorFuncNum' );
                if ( parentWindow['CKEDITOR'] )
                {
                    config.selectActionFunction = function( fileUrl, data )
                    {
                        parentWindow['CKEDITOR'].tools.callFunction( funcNum, fileUrl, data );
                    };

                    config.selectThumbnailActionFunction = config.selectActionFunction;
                }
                break;

            default:
                if ( parentWindow && parentWindow['FCK'] && parentWindow['SetUrl'] )
                {
                    action = 'fckeditor' ;
                    config.selectActionFunction = parentWindow['SetUrl'];

                    if ( !config.disableThumbnailSelection )
                        config.selectThumbnailActionFunction = parentWindow['SetUrl'];
                }
                else
                    action = null ;
        }

        config.action = action;

        // Always use 100% width and height when nested using this middle page.
        config.width = config.height = '100%';

        var ckfinder = new CKFinder( config );
        ckfinder.replace( 'ckfinder', config );
})();
    </script>
```

What I am trying to figure out how to do, is add that code to a page through the DOM. I know I can do it if I put this function in a >JS file, as I know how to call .JS files and have them load properly.

If I wanted to write that script out, as shown there, directly on the page, how would I do that? I have found some simple examples, like this:

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    var code = 'alert("hello world!");';
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = code;
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't seem to work when I put a long, multi-line, block of javascript in it. How can I do this?

Comment: use `<pre>` tag or change every end of line character to `<br>` tag

Comment: The simplest way to create a multi-line string is with ES6 string template literals. But why would you use `document.createElement('script');` to create and populate a script element dynamically if you're just going to fill it with JS that could've been directly included in its own script element?

Comment: This is being used as part of a GreeseMonkey script.

Comment: So it will be modifying a page, using Javascript, after it has already rendered. So I need to be able to get that JS code onto the page.

Comment: @JaromandaX that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm not tryint to PRINT this code onto the page. I'm trying to inject this script into a page using DOM manipulation.

Comment: So, using Javascript/DOM manipulation, how can I get that code above onto a page?

Answer (score -1):

DOM is a Tag based mark up structure. So a defined structure of Tags has to come in a defined order. Everything in DOM goes in Tags. If you want JavaScript in DOM, that will also be added to a Script Tag.
Within this tag you can put all your JavaScript and that will be just in the page for you.

Following link contains a JavaScript JQuery example that is the code on the same page and it is a very beginner level article with a detail on how to use Script on the page and how to use event handling etc.

[JavaScript Basic Tutorial on JQuery and Event Handling](http://www.djvsoft.com/jquery-events-event-handling/)

Comment: I'm not using jQuery

Comment: The point is you will do it in the script tag. Just as done in the tutorial. It doesnt matter if you use JQuery or not. That will remain same.